# Cosine similarity for very large dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, cosine-similarity

I am having trouble with calculating cosine similarity between large list of 100-dimensional vectors. When I use `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity`, I get `MemoryError` on my 16 GB machine. Each array fits perfectly in my memory but I get `MemoryError` during `np.dot()` internal call

Here's my use-case and how I am currently tackling it.

Here's my parent vector of 100-dimension which I need to compare with other 500,000 different vectors of same dimension (i.e. 100)

```
parent_vector = [1, 2, 3, 4 ..., 100]
```

Here are my child vectors (with some made-up random numbers for this example)

```
child_vector_1 = [2, 3, 4, ....., 101]
child_vector_2 = [3, 4, 5, ....., 102]
child_vector_3 = [4, 5, 6, ....., 103]
.......
.......
child_vector_500000 = [3, 4, 5, ....., 103]
```

My final goal is to get top-N child vectors (with their names such as `child_vector_1` and their corresponding cosine score) who have very high cosine similarity with the parent vector.

My current approach (which I know is inefficient and memory consuming):

**Step 1:** Create a super-dataframe of following shape

```
parent_vector         1,    2,    3, .....,    100   
child_vector_1        2,    3,    4, .....,    101   
child_vector_2        3,    4,    5, .....,    102   
child_vector_3        4,    5,    6, .....,    103   
......................................   
child_vector_500000   3,    4,    5, .....,    103
```

**Step 2:** Use

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity(df)
```

to get pair-wise cosine similarity between all vectors (shown in above dataframe)

**Step 3:** Make a list of tuple to store the `key` such as `child_vector_1` and value such as the cosine similarity number for all such combinations.

**Step 4:** Get the top-N using `sort()` of list -- so that I get the child vector name as well as its cosine similarity score with the parent vector.

> PS: I know this is highly inefficient but I couldn't think of a better
>   way to faster  compute cosine similarity between each of child vector
>   and parent vector and get the top-N values.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide some sample data to work with. also, please provide working solution on the small sample data & desired output so the SO community can suggest more efficient alternatives.

Comment: @sgokhales even I am facing the same problem. Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 9):

even though your (500000, 100) array (the parent and its children) fits into memory
any pairwise metric on it won't. The reason for that is that pairwise metric as the name suggests computes the distance for any two children. In order to store these distances you would need a (500000,500000) sized array of floats which if my calculations are right would take about 100 GB of memory.

Thankfully there is an easy solution for your problem. If I understand you correctly you only want to have the distance between child and parents which will result in a vector of length 500000 which is easily stored in memory.

To do this, you simply need to provide a second argument to cosine_similarity containing only the parent_vector

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(500000,100)) 
df['distances'] = cosine_similarity(df, df.iloc[0:1]) # Here I assume that the parent vector is stored as the first row in the dataframe, but you could also store it separately

n = 10 # or however many you want
n_largest = df['distances'].nlargest(n + 1) # this contains the parent itself as the most similar entry, hence n+1 to get n children
```

hope that solves your question.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, my dataframe is of size `(32593, 12)` I need to calculate the cosine similarty btw all the pairs i.e 32593*32593 and it doesn't fits into memory. How shall I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't even fit the entire corpus in memory so a solution for me was to load it gradually and compute cosine similarity on smaller batches, always retaining the least/most `n` (depending on your usecase) similar items:

```
data = []
iterations = 0
with open('/media/corpus.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)
        if len(data) <= 1000:
            pass
        else:
            print('Getting bottom k, iteration {x}'.format(x=iterations))
            data = get_bottom_k(data, 500)
            iterations += 1
filtered = get_bottom_k(data, 500) # final most different 500 texts in corpus


def get_bottom_k(corpus:list, k:int):
    pairwise_similarity = make_similarity_matrix(corpus) # returns pairwise similarity matrix
    sums = csr_matrix.sum(pairwise_similarity, axis=1)  # Similarity index for each item in corpus. Bigger > more
    sums = np.squeeze(np.asarray(sums))
    # similar to other txt.
    indexes = np.argpartition(sums, k, axis=0)[:k] # Bottom k in terms of similarity (-k for top and [-k:])
    return [corpus[i] for i in indexes]
```

This is by far an optimal solution but it's the easiest i found so far, maybe it will be of help to someone.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is insanely fast

```
child_vectors = np.array(child_vector_1, child_vector_2, ....., child_vector_500000)
input_norm = parent_vector / np.linalg.norm(parent_vector, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]
embed_norm =  child_vectors/ np.linalg.norm(child_vectors, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]
cosine_similarities = np.sort(np.round(np.dot(input_norm, embed_norm.T), 3)[0])[::-1]
paiswise_distances = 1 - cosine_similarities
```

Comment: Can you provide a time estimation?